# Converting wikipedia api response using Json.net

Tags: c#, json.net, wikipedia-api

I'm querying data using wikipedia api and would like to convert the result into a string[].

The query "test"

```
en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=test&format=json&callback=spellcheck
```

returns this result here:

```
spellcheck(["test",["Test cricket","Test","Testicle","Testudines","Testosterone","Test pilot","Test (assessment)","Testimonial match","Testimony","Testament (band)"]])
```

Can I use Json.net to drop or ignore the tag "spellcheck"?
If I convert the response using this code, the application crashes:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(response);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia's api (using JSON) assumes you're using JSONP. You could just drop the callback parameter completely from your query string:

> en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=test&format=json

Additionally, the result you're getting probably cannot be converted into a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`. If you look closely, it's actually an array where the first object is a string (search term) and the second is a list of strings (results).

The following worked for me:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
    @"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=test&format=json");

string[] searchResults = null;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        JArray objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        searchResults = objects[1].Select(j => j.Value<string>()).ToArray();
    }
}
```